# Reduce dimensionality with PCA after ORB

Tags: computer-vision

i try to reduce dimensionality of feature that have been extracted by using ORB with PCA then draw the keypoints that have been processed by PCA

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [14.0, 7.0]

e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
#read image and convert to RGB
image_normal = cv2.imread(image)
image_query = cv2.cvtColor(image_normal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_gray  = cv2.cvtColor(image_query, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#ORB function
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
keypoints, descriptor = orb.detectAndCompute(image_gray, None)

# Draw the keypoints 
image = cv2.drawKeypoints(image_query, keypoints,0,flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
mean, eigenvectors = cv2.PCACompute(image, np.mean(image, axis=0).reshape(1,-1))          

e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
t = (e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency() 

#Show Image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title('ORB Keypoints')
plt.show()

# Print the number of keypoints detected and time
print("\nNumber of keypoints Detected: ", len(keypoints))
print('Time Cost for ORB: ', (t))
```

as i try i got an error that says
    error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv- 
    python\opencv\modules\core\src\pca.cpp:72: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 
    data.channels() == 1 in function 'cv::PCA::operator ()'

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compute PCA on an image on which you've drawn the keypoints, rather than on the computed descriptors.

Comment: thank you for replying, how to compute descrptor with PCA, i'm really new on opencv